# Confusion about Amazon EC2 and S3

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Planning to host a PHP website with MySQL DB in Amazon Web Services, which AWS components should I choose? The website is just a dynamic website with a custom CMS, though a large amount of data are expected to be uploaded to the CMS.

I'm thinking to use Amazon EC2, with the following settings:

- t2.medium Linux with 1024GB x 2 Magnetic EBS Volume
- Data Transfer In & Out : 200 & 300 GB/Month

But I heard from others that I can use Amazon S3 to host websites, with the following settings:

- Storage: 3000GB
- PUT/COPY/POST/LIST Requests: 20000
- GET and other Requests: 10000
- Data Transfer In & Out : 200 & 300 GB/Month
- CloudFront Monthly Volume: 1000 GB/month (avg. Object size 30KB)

What are the differences? Which should I choose?

Comment: // You can host a static website on Amazon S3. On a static website, individual web pages include static content. They may also contain client-side scripts. By contrast, a dynamic website relies on server-side processing, including server-side scripts such as PHP, JSP, or ASP.NET. Amazon S3 does not support server-side scripting. // Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: You may also learn how to host dynamic sites at http://aws.amazon.com/websites/ . I hope that clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. So, do I need to use S3 for file storage, or use EBS volume is enough? How does EBS-optimized differ from non-EBS-optimized?

Comment: S3 works best for backups, imo. So, go with EBS. To learn the difference, please checkout http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/details/#piops

Comment: Thanks @Pothi. Can you put these in answer below, so that I can upvote & accept it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can host a static website on Amazon S3. On a static website,
>   individual web pages include static content. They may also contain
>   client-side scripts. By contrast, a dynamic website relies on
>   server-side processing, including server-side scripts such as PHP,
>   JSP, or ASP.NET. Amazon S3 does not support server-side scripting.

Ref: [Hosting a Static Website on Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)

You may also learn how to host dynamic sites at [aws.amazon.com/websites](http://aws.amazon.com/websites).

S3 works best for backups, imo. So, go with EBS. To learn different EBS options, please checkout [aws.amazon.com/ebs/details/#piops](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/details/#piops)

Comment: Since the OP is planning to run MySQL, it might be appropriate to have a look at RDS, too: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/. With that one can have automated backups for the database etc.